# How to write this in Linq? group and get max

Tags: linq, group-by, max

```
select * 
from monthStatistics ms 
    where ms.beloneMonth = 
         (
            select max(ms2.beloneMonth) 
            from monthStatistics ms2 
            where ms.materialDictionaryId = ms2.materialDictionaryId 
            and ms.locationId = ms2.locationId 
            and ms.price=ms2.price
          )
```

Sample Data

```
id  beloneMonth       materialDictinaryId    price  acount
1   2013/7            1                      100    200
2   2013/7            2                      100    200
3   2013/8            1                      100    200
4   2013/8            1                      200    200
```

Result:

```
id  beloneMonth       materialDictinaryId    price  acount
2   2013/7            2                      100    200
3   2013/8            1                      100    200
4   2013/8            1                      200    200
```

group and get the max month row.

Comment: The SQL you have given does not really show what you are trying to do. We need to first FIX your SQL then we need to convert to Linq.

Comment: You may check my Edit. What you need is Group By `id` and then get the rows which have the max `beloneMonth` for each `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return the row(s) of `monthStatistics` which has the `max` value in `beloneMonth`

```
monthStatistics
    .GroupBy(x=>x.id)
    .SelectMany
    (
        x=>
        x.Where
        (
            z=>
            z.beloneMonth == x.Max(y=>y.beloneMonth)
        )
    );
```